# Why the vectored python code to compare values across rows is not working?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a dataframe as:

```
    data = [ ['A',1,200,200],
             ['A',2,-30,],
             ['A',3,500,],
             ['A',4,10,],
             ['A',5,-45,],
             ['B',1,30,500],
             ['B',2,12,],
             ['B',3,50,]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['batch','idx','op_sum', 'var3'])
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
    batch   idx     op_sum      var3
    A        1       200         200
    A        2       -30         -30
    A        3       500         -30         
    A        4        10         -30
    A        5       -45         -45        
    B        1        30         500        
    B        2        12          12        
    B        3        50          12
```

Logic being:

```
If cur row(op_sum) < previous row(var3) then  
 cur row(var3) = cur row(op_sum)  
else cur row(var3) = previous row(var3)
```

Note: I can achieve using iterrows and iloc but its not practical for millions of rows.

I have gotten this far with the vectorization:

```
#(a)   
    df.var3.ix[(df.op_sum<df.var3.shift()) | (df.var3.shift().isnull())] = df.op_sum.ix[(df.op_sum<df.var3.shift()) | (df.var3.shift().isnull())]    

#(b)  
    df.var3.ix[(df.op_sum>df.var3.shift())] = df.var3.shift().ix[(df.op_sum>df.var3.shift())]
```

This yields the following:

```
    batch   idx     op_sum      var3
    A        1       200         200
    A        2       -30         -30
    A        3       500         -30         
    A        4        10         -10  #Not Good
    A        5       -45         -45        
    B        1        30         -45  #Not Good   
    B        2        12          12        
    B        3        50          12
```

When op_sum = 10 > var3.shift() = -30 it should give me var3 = -30 and similarly for the other not good value!

Also when I try to perform this operation (a) and (b) by doing `df.groupby('batch')` first, it gives me `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'ix' of 'SeriesGroupby' objects, try using 'apply' method` !

Please help me get over the finish line. Much appreciated.

Comment: why the expected value of batch B idx 1 is 500?

Comment: It's the start of the new Group and so the value is already there in the start data

Comment: Yeah but the start should be 30 for B. I was writing an answer with `cummin` until I saw that 500 which doesn't fit into the data.

Comment: That's the tricky part. The start value for every batch group is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummin.html):

```
df['var3'] = df.groupby('batch')['op_sum'].cummin()
print (df)
  batch  idx  op_sum  var3
0     A    1     200   200
1     A    2     -30   -30
2     A    3     500   -30
3     A    4      10   -30
4     A    5     -45   -45
5     B    1      30    30
6     B    2      12    12
7     B    3      50    12
```